# react native, react native android app working in emulator and device, however for ios its showing blank white screen in device and simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

i am new bee to react native, when i run myapp in android it works in device and emulator both, but when i run same app in ios (from xcode), it just shows plain white screen in ios device and simulator.

metro server is running.

these are metro server logs.

```
[Sat Jul 23 2022 19:21:25.140]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-applovin-max/src/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-applovin-max/src/AppLovinMAXAdView.js -> node_modules/react-native-applovin-max/src/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Sat Jul 23 2022 19:21:25.150]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
[Sat Jul 23 2022 19:21:25.150]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
[Sat Jul 23 2022 19:21:25.150]  LOG      redux-persist/stateReconciler: rehydrated keys 'settings, session, deviceInfo, _persist'
[Sat Jul 23 2022 19:21:26.900]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

please help me to get it fixed. already wasted 2 days to figure out this issue.

```
2022-07-23 06:51:21.227838-0700 myapps[1240:116275] [myTarget info] SDK autoinit started
2022-07-23 06:51:21.251646-0700 myapps[1240:116277] [myTarget info] SDK initialized
2022-07-23 06:51:21.277518-0700 myapps[1240:116039] [native] Running application myapps! ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})

2022-07-23 06:51:21.292759-0700 myapps[1240:116277] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.9.2.0 started
2022-07-23 06:51:21.293125-0700 myapps[1240:116277] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2022-07-23 06:51:21.296473-0700 myapps[1240:116039] +[RNFBSharedUtils getConfigBooleanValue:key:defaultValue:] [Line 157] RNFBCrashlyticsInit crashlytics_debug_enabled via RNFBMeta: 0
2022-07-23 06:51:21.296499-0700 myapps[1240:116039] +[RNFBSharedUtils getConfigBooleanValue:key:defaultValue:] [Line 160] RNFBCrashlyticsInit crashlytics_debug_enabled final value: 0
2022-07-23 06:51:21.296512-0700 myapps[1240:116039] +[RNFBCrashlyticsInitProvider isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled] [Line 49] RNFBCrashlyticsInit isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled after checking crashlytics_debug_enabled: 0
2022-07-23 06:51:21.296529-0700 myapps[1240:116039] +[RNFBCrashlyticsInitProvider configureWithApp:] [Line 101] RNFBCrashlyticsInit initialization successful
2022-07-23 06:51:21.322156-0700 myapps[1240:116290] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2022-07-23 06:51:21.334480-0700 myapps[1240:116276] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2022-07-23 06:51:21.334738-0700 myapps[1240:116276] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [...]) to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2022-07-23 06:51:21.492619-0700 myapps[1240:116277] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS025026] Deferring to Firebase for event data collection
2022-07-23 06:51:23.386157-0700 myapps[1240:116277] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Warning: NSUncaughtExceptionHandler is 'GADRegisterExceptionHandler' in '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E7DB67AE-7139-49E5-B7BF-5CB022F7FF5E/myapps.app/myapps'
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGABRT has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGBUS has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGFPE has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGILL has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGSEGV has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGSYS has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGTRAP has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
2022-07-23 06:51:24.661576-0700 myapps[1240:116288] [javascript] '[ENV]', 'https://api.myapps.com'
2022-07-23 06:51:24.734493-0700 myapps[1240:116288] [javascript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-applovin-max/src/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-applovin-max/src/AppLovinMAXAdView.js -> node_modules/react-native-applovin-max/src/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2022-07-23 06:51:24.742989-0700 myapps[1240:116288] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
2022-07-23 06:51:24.747625-0700 myapps[1240:116288] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2022-07-23 06:51:24.749831-0700 myapps[1240:116288] [javascript] redux-persist/stateReconciler: rehydrated keys 'settings, session, deviceInfo, _persist'
2022-07-23 06:51:24.781972-0700 myapps[1240:116277] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C6:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-07-23 06:51:24.782097-0700 myapps[1240:116285] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C6] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2022-07-23 06:51:24.782117-0700 myapps[1240:116285] TCP Conn 0x282b51550 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2022-07-23 06:51:24.846974-0700 myapps[1240:116039] [native] Running surface LogBox ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 11;
})
2022-07-23 06:51:24.847370-0700 myapps[1240:116288] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2022-07-23 06:51:25.848187-0700 myapps[1240:116039] [native] Failed to mount LogBox within 1s
2022-07-23 06:51:26.564688-0700 myapps[1240:116039] Preloading CNContactViewController
2022-07-23 06:51:26.577362-0700 myapps[1240:116039] [Graphics] UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range. Set a breakpoint on UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents to debug. This message will only be logged once.
```

also i can see following logs in chrome debugger:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: even ios app in debug mode doesn't work.

Comment: let me know if any other info required, i will update question or attach info in comments.

Comment: When you run the app in Xcode, you don't get any errors? Did you run `pod install` after installing any new packages?  `Native module cannot be null` means it's missing native code. Also, try fixing the require cycle, they can crash the app.